# Does having multiple class files in android app slow down the app?

Tags: java, android

Am not sure if i'll be able capture the essence of my doubt, but i'll give it a try anyway!
 My doubt is about creating lightweight android apps. I read a few sites and all commonly talk about using layouts judiciously(and passing objects and other things). But no one ever made it clear if the number of class is directly proportionally to causing the app to lag down? I understand using multiple class which send class objects to and from them will cause it to lag but for the sake of Modularity am doing so!

One such place is passing the control from a login button's onclick to another class to process the connectivity and starting a new activity without freezing the app.
(I know this isn't the right way to do it but still just for the sake of example.)
So here i'll mostly be sending context of the activity to different class!

So i can sum my doubts to two questions-
**1. Does multiple java classes slow down an app(and at what range to keep them)?**
**2.And will passing context take just as much amount of memory as passing an ordinary object?**
**P.S** Link to a question about performance creating lightweight app - [Tips for lightweight Android Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998636/tips-for-lightweight-android-applications)
Any feed back is appreciated!
Thanks!